# Magento: get roles and users

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, roles

How can I get collection of all roles (System->Permission->Roles) and users which has this role?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get all the Roles

```
       $roles = Mage::getModel('admin/roles')->getCollection();
       foreach($roles as $role):
          echo '<br/>Role : '.$role->getId()." | ".$role->getRoleName();
       endforeach;
```

To get the Role users

```
      $roles_users = Mage::getResourceModel('admin/roles_user_collection');
      foreach($roles_users as $roleuser):
       $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($roleuser->getUserId());
       echo '<br/>User : '.$user->getUsername()." | ".$user->getFirstname();
      endforeach;
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you also now how to get users with this roles? :)

Comment: @AlexK kindly find my updated answer ;-) Let me know if you have any doubts with this.

Answer (score 3):

You can also get all role user ids with this

```
$roles = Mage::getModel('admin/roles')->load($roleId)->getRoleUsers();
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post when I looked for a way to select all admin users belonging to a specific user role. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35926429/5409507) and [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/97947/24818).) The question here could be read as if Alex wants the admin users for each role. Since the answer does not sort by admin role, I would like to offer the following solution:

```
$usersByRole = array();
$adminRoles = Mage::getModel('admin/roles')->getCollection();
foreach($adminRoles as $adminRole) {
    $adminRoleId = $adminRole->getId(); 
    $adminRoleUserCollection = Mage::getModel('admin/role')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', ['eq'=>$adminRoleId])
        ->join(['user' => 'admin/user'], 'user.user_id=main_table.user_id');
    $usersByRole[$adminRole->getRoleName()] = $adminRoleUserCollection;
}
```